# Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; jQuery font error : 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

Tags: nginx, fonts, content-security-policy

Content-Security-Policy HTTP Header Reference: 
https://content-security-policy.com/

Chrome error:  jQuery font error : 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

I recently had a new Content-Security-Policy header enforced for our web servers and ran into this issue for jQuery 1.11.3 fonts.  Unfortunately it is a legacy web application and relies on this older version of jQuery.

Is there an example of how to set the font-src header correctly for NGINX web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/plentz/6737338):

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'";
```

particularly relevant is:

```
font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com;
```

basically if you have a bunch of rules you should split each one with a semicolon then "special" ones you should have in quotes and any domains like fonts.google.com can just be listed with a spacebar no quotes. It is exactly the same syntax meta tag Http equivalent Content-Security-Policy headers.

Comment: if you show the full error it might show the exact domain you are trying to get the fonts from such as fonts.google.com or whatnot I'm not sure what domain your jQuery is loading your fonts from.